# Advantage of fragments on Screen rotation

Tags: android

```
   I wonder if there is any advantage of fragments, on screen rotation.
    Generally fragments get destroyed followed by activity. Is there something that fragments retain while doing so?
```

onDestroy() method is called both in the activity and fragments.

Comment: Please look up setRetainInstance() method of fragment.

Answer (score 0):

I can try to figure out advantage of `Fragment` on *Screen rotation*.

**Realtime app problem is:**

> Android is the potentially frequent *destruction* and *reconstruction* of an `Activity`. The most common time this occurs is when the user rotates the device between horizontal and portrait orientations (Screen rotation).
>
> This *crashing* usually occurs because device orientation changes cause the **Android framework** to tear down the displayed Activity along within any contained Views, and then to fully reconstruct the `Activity/View` hierarchy. Any references to the Activity or to the Views within the Activity suddenly become invalid. Similarly any references within the Activity or Views that were set as a result of a *user action* or similar are now lost.

There are a number of ways to deal with this issue but one of the easiest is to **take advantage of Fragments**.

Things to keep in mind:

> Fragments won’t automatically resolve this issue because, by default, when the Activity is torn-down in response to an orientation change the Fragment contained within the Activity is also torn down along with any contained Views.

The **solution** lies in an underused method: **`Fragment.setRetainInstance`** with a value of `true`.

**why?**

> Calling `setRetainInstance` with a value of `true` causes Android to preserve the `Fragment` across the *teardown/reconstruction* cycle of an `Activity`. Along with the `Fragment`, the `Views` or other object references contained within the Fragment or Views remain.

With `setRetainInstance(true)` called on a Fragment instance.when an orientation change occurs, Android…

- Holds a reference to the Fragment instance
- Tears down the old Activity instance
- Creates a new Activity instance
- Attaches the preserved Fragment instance to the new Activity instance

Answer (score 0):

you must add

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

in parent Activity also calling

```
setRetainInstance(true)
```

in onCreate of fragment